# How to create an anonymous pipe between 2 child processes and know their pids (while not using files/named pipes)?

Tags: bash, exec, wait, pid

Please note that this questions was edited after a couple of comments I received. Initially I wanted to split my goal into smaller pieces to make it simpler (and perhaps expand my knowledge on various fronts), but it seems I went too far with the simplicity :). So, here I am asking the big question.

Using bash, is there a way one can actually create an anonymous pipe between two child processes and know their pids?

The reason I'm asking is when you use the classic pipeline, e.g.

```
cmd1 | cmd2 &
```

you lose the ability to send signals to cmd1. In my case the actual commands I am running are these

```
./my_web_server | ./my_log_parser &
```

my_web_server is a basic web server that dump a lot of logging information to it's stdout
my_log_parser is a log parser that I wrote that reads through all the logging information it receives from my_web_server and it basically selects only certain values from the log (in reality it actually stores the whole log as it received it, but additionally it creates an extra csv file with the values it finds).

The issue I am having is that my_web_server actually never stops by itself (it is a web server, you don't want that from a web server :)). So after I am done, I need to stop it myself. I would like for the bash script to do this when I stop it (the bash script), either via SIGINT or SIGTERM.

For something like this, traps are the way to go. In essence I would create a trap for INT and TERM and the function it would call would kill my_web_server, but... I don't have the pid and even though I know I could look for it via ps, I am looking for a pretty solution :).

Some of you might say: "Well, why don't you just kill my_log_parser and let my_web_server die on its own with SIGPIPE?". The reason why I don't want to kill it is when you kill a process that's at the end of the pipeline, the output buffer of the process before it, is not flushed. Ergo, you lose stuff.

I've seen several solutions here and in other places that suggested to store the pid of my_web_server in a file. This is a solution that works. It is possible to write the pipeline by fiddling with the filedescriptors a bit. I, however don't like this solution, because I have to generate files. I don't like the idea of creating arbitrary files just to store a 5-character PID :).

What I ended up doing for now is this:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap " " HUP

fifo="$( mktemp -u "$( basename "${0}" ).XXXXXX" )"
mkfifo "${fifo}"

<"${fifo}" ./my_log_parser &
parser_pid="$!"

>"${fifo}" ./my_web_server &
server_pid="$!"

rm "${fifo}"

trap '2>/dev/null kill -TERM '"${server_pid}"'' INT TERM

while true; do
  wait "${parser_pid}" && break
done
```

This solves the issue with me not being able to terminate my_web_server when the script receives SIGINT or SIGTERM. It seems more readable than any hackery fiddling with file descriptors in order to eventually use a file to store my_web_server's pid, which I think is good, because it improves the readability.

But it still uses a file (named pipe). Even though I know it uses the file (named pipe) for my_web_server and my_log_parser to talk (which is a pretty good reason) and the file gets wiped from the disk very shortly after it's created, it's still a file :).

Would any of you guys know of a way to do this task without using any files (named pipes)?

Comment: I suspect you'd get a deadlock in normal circumstances (i.e. a process that outputs stuff rather than sleep) here: the process would be blocked until the shell reads that output, but if the shell's waiting on the process to end... Can'f find any docs on this though.

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  Generally `sleep` does not output anything, so why are you tying it to file descriptor 3?  You are no reading it anyhow.

Comment: Hey guys, I am sorry I did not make this a bit clearer in the initial post. My use case does not utilize sleep.It actually starts another binary (a proxy server to be exact) whose output I am trying to catch in my bash script and process it. I know I can pretty much do this the silly 'while read i; do blah blah; done < <( ./my_proxy_server )'-way, but I don't particularly like the fact that when a script using this approach receives INT or TERM, it simply dies without telling ./my_proxy_server to bugger off too :)

Comment: @PetrMOTEJLEK:  see further edit, hope it helps

Comment: @PetrMOTEJLEK:  Yet Another Edit to my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Bash `man` pages:

```
!      Expands  to  the  process ID of the most recently executed back-
       ground (asynchronous) command.
```

You are not running a background command, you are running process substitution to read to file descriptor 3.

The following works, but I'm not sure if it is what you are trying to achieve:

```
sleep 120 &
child_pid="$!"

wait "${child_pid}"
sleep 120
```

Edit:
Comment was: *I know I can pretty much do this the silly 'while read i; do blah blah; done < <( ./my_proxy_server )'-way, but I don't particularly like the fact that when a script using this approach receives INT or TERM, it simply dies without telling ./my_proxy_server to bugger off too :)*

So, it seems like your problem stems from the fact that it is not so easy to get the PID of the proxy server.  So, how about using your own named pipe, with the `trap` command:

```
pipe='/tmp/mypipe'
mkfifo "$pipe"
./my_proxy_server > "$pipe" &

child_pid="$!"
echo "child pid is $child_pid"

# Tell the proxy server to bugger-off
trap 'kill $child_pid' INT TERM

while read
do
    echo $REPLY
    # blah blah blah
done < "$pipe"

rm "$pipe"
```

You could probably also use `kill %1` instead of using `$child_pid`.

YAE (Yet Another Edit):
You ask how to get the PIDS from:

```
./my_web_server | ./my_log_parser &
```

Simples, sort of.  To test I used `sleep`, just like your original.

```
sleep 400 | sleep 500 &
jobs -l
```

Gives:

```
[1]+  8419 Running                 sleep 400
      8420 Running                 | sleep 500 &
```

So its just a question of extracting those PIDS:

```
pid1=$(jobs -l|awk 'NR==1{print $2}')
pid2=$(jobs -l|awk 'NR==2{print $1}')
```

I hate calling `awk` twice here, but anything else is just jumping through hoops.

Comment: Hi @cdarke, I see. I know I am substituting, but I also know that a child bash process gets spawned. I would have expected for this to act somewhat similarly. Well, obviously it does not.

Comment: Hi, funny thing. We just both edited our comments :). The named pipe is exactly what I did (when you look at my newly edited question). I think it's by far the most readable and transparent solution. Also kudos to you for cleanly identifying my pid problem without me saying it (where did you get the crystal ball?) :). However... I am still a bit turned down by the fact that my script creates files even though they are actually pipes and are used for a good purpose :)

Comment: @PetrMOTEJLEK: Great minds think alike :-)  What I don't get though is that if the parent process dies with a SIGINT or SIGTERM then it should kill the server with a SIGHUP, unless it is trapping HUP itself?

Comment: Will this (`jobs -l`) actually work even when that script is ran without job control? I.e. from started non-interactively, e.g. from cron? I am not sure. But nevertheless it seems like a good idea.

Comment: Too bad you can't just dup some "special" fd that would give you an anonymous pipe.

Comment: @PetrMOTEJLEK:  well you can do that in Perl, Python, and C.   `jobs` will only work with job control - that is why `kill` is a shell-builtin rather than an external program.  The alternative would be to use `ps`.  Are you on Linux?  The reason I ask is because you can get magic from `/proc`.